# How would I calculate the bending stress on a structure like this?

Tags: machine-design

[image]
The structure is a a linear and ratchet pawl and this is the free body diagram of pawl that is under bending and compression and I am just trying to figure out the bending stress caused by the moment arm. Thanks

Comment: what is stopping it from rotating?

Comment: joojaa Exactly, it isn't in equilibrium. If the fixed point is indeed fixed then there must be a torque about it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$M = Fa$ pb-in

$S = bt^3/6$ in^3

$f_b = M/S$ psi

Comment: I think you need a cosine for F*a.

Comment: @JohnHoltz Distance "a" is the lever arm in parallel to the centerline of the support and the force. "b" is the width normal to "a".

Comment: Right! That makes sense now.

Comment: @JohnHoltz Thanks for asking, I hope the OP can figure it out too.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the point under the pawl at 0.25in $A,$ and the point at a distance of $1.5*2/3 =1in \  B$. For simplicity, we will handle this as a column, even tho it's too short.

We have to calculate the reactions of $A$ and $B$ to balance the overturning moment of $$M= 6000lb*4cos(60)=12000lb.in$$

This counterclockwise moment is canceled by reactions at A and B. The force at B is the sum of the triangular compression stress from the support acting at its $CG= 2/3$ from the base of the stress triangle. so by inspection, we notice A is tension and B compression (later we take care of axial force).

$$\Sigma M_O =12000lbin=R_B*1in \quad R_B=R_A=12000lb.$$

The compression stress triangle has a base of 1.5 in and a height of
$$H=12000=1.5*h/2 \quad h/2=8klb \quad h=16klb$$

So the compression stress grows from zero at A with a Slope of $S=16klbs/1.5in$
This stress and the tension at A work as a couple and have to be added or subtracted from $6000lb*sin60/area$ normal stress.

A diagram would be helpful, but I got to run.

### EDIT

Added a diagram showing the forces and the reactions just for the moment the axial 5196 lbs should b added algebraically to the reactions. The pawl acts as a cantilever beam under the transverse load of $$P=3000 \ and \ axial \ load \ of \ N=5196$$

'

[image: moments and forces]